# How to show pin's latitude and longitude on map (Android Studio)

Tags: android, google-maps

How to get latitude and longitude from pin that user dropped ?  Like Google map, we click a pin on the map , it shows the latitude and longitude about the pin. Could anyone help me ? Thanks a lot.

Like the picture ,it shows latitude and longitude .

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7mkI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class YOURACTIVITY extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback

private GoogleMap mMap;
<--
OnCreate
 SupportMapFragment map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        map.getMapAsync(this);

-->

  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        double mLat = LATITUDE;
        double mLon = LONTITUDE;
        LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(mLat, mLon);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylocation).snippet("TEXT BELLOW TITLE").title("TITLE")).showInfoWindow();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation,15));
    }
```

UPDATE
Try to do add something like this. Create custom layout and add information

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View view = MainActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_custom, null);


                TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_title);
                TextView snippetTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_snippet);

                titleTextView.setText(marker.getTitle());
                snippetTextView.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                return view;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I updated answer, try to do custom layout if it will work for you

Comment: Excuse me , what is  getLayoutInflater ?

Comment: It is a method from android Activity. But you can have an inflater from outside an activity with LayoutInflater.from(context) if you need this.

Comment: The first one worked, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this efficient solution:

```
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    pin.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());        
    //Create a marker object
    Marker myMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));

    //And now you can use it's values
    myMarker.getPosition().latitude;
    myMarker.getPosition().longitude;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post images for example. I add a new photo on the post. Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be adding a new marker over the map every time it is tapped on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setOnMarkerDragListener method:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        double latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        double longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post images for example. I add a new photo on the post. Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: You can either update the marker and show an info window with 'marker.showInfoWindow();' or, as the image you provide place another layout over the map and update it's content in the onMarkerDragEnd method (placing the map and this layout inside a FrameLayout so that this layout can overlap the map) and have this 'window' placed always at the same place and update its contents and visibility. And also, using a BottomSheetDialogFragment could be a good option to show the information depending on the effect you desire.

Comment: In your case I would not use the infoWindow ( goo.gl/H559at ) and instead go for the FrameLayout with the map and the other ViewGroup (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout...) and update its content and visibility on the onMarkerDragEnd as it seems that you want this info placed always at the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is to use the [Marker.getPosition()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getPosition()#getPosition()) method, maybe in a toast:

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    LatLng pos = marker.getPosition();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Point coordinates: " + pos.latitude 
        + ", " + pos.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry , not Toast. The text will come with pin.

Comment: Well, it was an example; of course you have to construct your own widget if you want it to look similar to what you show in your pic